# Display custom link in static blocks

Tags: magento-1.9, static-block

I have a few links(containing image and title) to some of my store's pages, this can be a filtered search page, or a category page or any other URL.
I want to manage these link from an static block in a way that admin doesn't have to deal with html coding.

For example, I want them to enter something like this:
`{{image_url="/images/blahblah.jpg" href="http://mystore.com/accessories.html?price=-100" title="Accessories under $100"}}`

And I want to render each item like below:

```
    <li>
        <a href="http://mystore.com/accessories.html?price=-100" title="Accessories under $100">
            <img src="{{media url="/images/blahblah.jpg"}}" alt="Accessories under $100">
            <h3>Accessories under $100</h3>
           <div class="over">
               Show all products
           </div>
       </a>
    </li>
```

Any suggestions on how this can be done is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can add like normal image tag used in HTML. 
[image: link image]